# How to report the parameter learning results from dynamic Bayesian network for test and control groups in a research paper?

Tags: bayesian, anova, bayesian-network

I have a Dynamic Bayesian Network which I used in my research. Network is shown below:
[image]

It was employed in an educational video game and I ran the experiment for test and control groups separately. Parameter learning for the two groups resulted in different conditional probabilities and I could explain the differences that occurred. Below is an example of the learned probabilities for the test group:

[image]

I have a lot more tables for the param learning results and have two questions in this regard. First, is there a better way to report these results instead of using so many tables? Second, similar to what we do in classical ANOVA statistics where we compare the results from test and control group, is there a good way to compare the differences in Bayesian statistics? Is there a better way to interpret the results?